# Percentages in table calculations

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to calculate a churn rate based on the following table:
[image]

For example, there were 22 entries in January, 4 left in the 1st month.  I want to have percentages following the logic:

1. 1 - 4/22 = 0,81
2. 1-4/22 - 1/22 = 0,77

In Tableau I create a calculated field:

```
    1 - 

SUM([Number of Records]) / TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records]))

- ZN(LOOKUP(SUM([Number of Records]) / TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records])), -1))
```

But it works only for the first 2 months:
[image]
Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself

```
IF NOT ISNULL(SUM([Number of Records])) THEN
(TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records]))
- RUNNING_SUM( SUM([Number of Records]) ) 
+ ZN(SUM([Number of Records])) - SUM([Number of Records]))  / TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records]))
END
```